# Does the colour quality of a VM affect it's performance?

Tags: color-palette, remote-connections

If you have a remote connection or a screenshare or whatever system where you're using a machine to look at another desktop on another machine, does the amount of colours affect the performance?

I'm not sure how Citrix VM vs Mikogo vs UltraVNC work with displaying information, but I've always guessed it's a combination of sending mouse and keyboard instructions and then refreshing the image to show what the display of the desktop is.

Now, if you have a .gif file with 265 colours, it's going to be smaller in filesize than one with 65million colours, because the palette is smaller, if I recall my image manipulation correctly.

Would a similar logic apply to remote connections? Would remoting into a machine and having 8-bit colours perform better than the same machine displaying 32 bit colour?
[alt text http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f5/Plum.jpg](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f5/Plum.jpg)

Comment: This may or may not be a thinly veiled attempt to see if there is a reason to have 8-bit citrix sessions over 32-bit. Hatched colours to get blending happening hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that deppends on configuration, the VM can be running on 32bit colors, but if you configure the transmission to be done in 8bit, it'll be faster, you can configure it to disable the VM background when accessing it to make the performance even better

Comment: Is that because of the amount of information required to transfer an image of the device to the viewing program is less? I understand a blue-desktop would be less than a bliss background, but I didn't know if that logic was valid to apply to this situation.

Comment: It depends on the protocol. Whether you're using RDP, ICA or some other remote protocol to transmit high-color does require a certain amount of overhead for bitmaps, however for typical resources such as icons or other windowing it really shouldn't make much difference.  These solutions are less about transferring the screen and more about trasnferring instructions to build the screen (e.g. drawrect, fillrect, etc.)